# Running into an issue scraping off of an API page?

Tags: r, json, web-scraping

I had previously been able to run this code, but it looks like something has changed. I'm attempting to scrape JSON from a website — the goal is to iterate through a bunch of numbers and compile the information on my end.

For my purposes, this is the part of the code that is breaking:

```
"https://api.mtgstocks.com/prints/11521/prices" %>% 
  readLines()
```

This generates the error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://api.mtgstocks.com/prints/11521/prices'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open URL 'https://api.mtgstocks.com/prints/11521/prices': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
```

I run into similar issues using GET and geturl. I realize that I may be blocked, but the confusing part is that I'm able to access the page and all the data from my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using a variety of different ways. My guess is that they recently changed their policy. Here's a way that still worked for me using `RSelenium` to automate a browser to access the data:

```
# load libraries
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)

# define target url
url <- "https://api.mtgstocks.com/prints/11521/prices"


# start RSelenium ------------------------------------------------------------

rD <- rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4550L, chromever = NULL)
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$open()

# Navigate to webpage -----------------------------------------------------
remDr$navigate(url)


# click on raw data tab ------------------------------------
remDr$findElement(using = "css",value = "#rawdata-tab")$clickElement()


# pull the webpage html
# then read it
page_html <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()

# find the html element where the json data is stored
# then extract the text
json_text <- page_html %>% 
            html_node(".data") %>% 
             html_text()

# read in the data using a json reading function
data <- fromJSON(json_text)
```